# When is it realistic to model diffusion without advection?

Tags: colloids, diffusion

Brownian motion abounds in nature, but so does drift current.  In theoretical models of solutions and colloidal suspensions it is sometimes assumed that advection is negligible.  I'm wondering if this is a natural assumption to make, or if it is generally better (e.g. more informative, whether in a positive or negative sense) in settings where accuracy is desired to account for correlated motion owing to mesoscopic currents from the beginning.

This question is partly motivated by the following paradox (or non-paradox, as the case may be): correlated motion of solute and suspended particles from bulk currents is only irrelevant when the particles are near enough to a solid surface, like a porous material or substrate, for those currents to be negligible.  But no surface is perfectly rigid, and to some extent each exposed surface may act as an additional source of random current: could vibrations transmitted by the substrate introduce additional correlations in particle diffusion that depend on the substrate-solvent interface?

Finally, is it known to what extent hydrodynamic interactions between suspended particles account for drift induced by boundary fluctuations (e.g. deformations or perturbations to the container walls), or would these be better modeled as an independent source of randomness?

A related question would be, *is it possible to reproduce Brownian dynamics with hydrodynamic correlations through a randomly fluctuating flow field?* (and if so, *to what extent should these fluctuations involve independent activity or spontaneous motion of the particles, i.e. as though they were pulled along by invisible forces, and to what extent should the particles be driven by currents that are induced by fluctuating boundary conditions?*)

References:
Hydrodynamic coupling to a wall (i.e. effect of random currents on the diffusion tensor, both away from and near a perfectly rigid wall)
https://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/leshouches2/node20.html

"Currents" induced by fluctuating surfaces:
https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/making-sound-waves/

Comment: Could you add a reference or two in support of the proposed arguments?

Comment: Or references in support of the claims and choice of terminology?  (e.g. that 'bulk currents' produce 'correlated motion' only when particles are far away from surfaces, and that surfaces are capable of generating random currents?)

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you want the system to be homogeneous from the start or not. I guess engineers want well stirred reactors in their study of reactions but if you are studying reactions in the  seas, for example, then advection is going to be important. How do your surfaces get vibrations? Do you mean waves?

Comment: @porphyrin: I'm not entirely sure what you mean in your first sentence (it should be clear that this question is more about understanding how things are than trying to force anything), but vibrations in solids have several origins, including thermal excitation, which can become more pronounced at large wavelengths depending on the shape of the material at large scales.  I could imagine vibrations playing a non-insignificant role in the diffusion of colloids near a graphene sheet, for example, or near a thin wire.